# How can I control the render/rerender of a child component on .map()

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Basically, my task looks like this: I need to apply animation to each first element of the array.

My case looks like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-austin-c5sx53?file=/src/App.tsx

But currently when some data updating, my parent have rerender and then my child component have  rerender alos. And I have my animation playing several times, and on all elements of the array added to the child at the same time.

By Google I found options like usePrevious (hooK) / componentDidUpdate / wrap in React.memo / useCallback etc. And some why it did not help.

So it is looks like i need to control my rerender of my component. But i dont know how to do it properly.

Can some one help me? Mb with some example, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to condition your classname on your child and use setTimeout on useEffect to toggle your classname, something like :

```
export function Child(props: ChildProps) {
  // Some Child
  const { someCildContent } = props;
  const [isAnimated, setAnimated] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => setAnimated(false), 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className={isAnimated ? "someAnimation" : "toto"}>
      {someCildContent.someData}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Say me if it's ok

Comment: Hi.  No (( Still the same situation... If paret rerender. But i faind the way. If i will put isAnimated state in store. It will work only for 1st child correctly. But i cant reSet it, bec. i have between some steps.